# Create JIRA issue via SOAP API and PHP

Tags: php, soap, jira

I cannot create an issue via the SOAP API in PHP. I tried this:

```
$soapClient = new SoapClient("http://jira:9090/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2?wsdl");
$token = $soapClient->login('user', 'pass');
$issue=array(
    'type'=>3,
    'priority'=>3,
    'project'=>'XXX',
    'duedate'=>time(),
    'components'=>'',
    'versions'=>'',
    'fixVersions'=>'',
    'assignee'=>'user1',
    'reporter'=>'user1',
    'environment'=>'',
    'description'=>'test',
    'summary'=>'test',
    'timetracking'=>'',
    'attachment'=>'',
    'labels'=>''
);
$soapClient->createIssue($token, $issue);
```

But when I run this script, the new issue is not created in JIRA. Can somebody help me with this problem?

Comment: Does the userid 'user' in the authentication have permission to set the reporter field? Also try without setting the duedate field since the result of time is unlikely to be in the expected format.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that:

- the project name is correct
- issue type number 3 exists and contains all those fields
- `user1` (from the issue fields) has permissions to be assignee and reporter  for this project (try to do it manually)
- `user` (from the authentication) has permissions to create new issues in this project (log in manually with the user and try to create an issue)

The `duedate'=>time()` is working fine for me. Actually, I took your code, changed the project,reporter and assingee names and it worked for me, under Jira 4.4.4 .

The weird thing is that if there was a problem you were  suppose to get an error, how are you trying to execute the php file? try to run it manually to check for errors. To do that create a PHP file with the following header:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
```

give it running permissions `chmod +x myscript.php`   and execute it `./myscript.php`. If you are running it from your web server check `/var/log/httpd/error_log` for errors. Make sure you have the SOAP installed :

```
[root@localhost]# cat /etc/php.d/soap.ini
; Enable soap extension module
extension=soap.so
```

If you find any error update the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue query must be an object

```
$issueQuery = new stdClass;
```

All your fields must be in an array

```
$customFields = array();
```

Your customfields must be an object

```
$fieldOBJ = new stdClass;
$fieldOBJ->customfieldId = 'customfield_10237';
$fieldOBJ->key = '';
$fieldOBJ->values = array(utf8_encode($value));
```

Add it to the array

```
$customFields[] = $fieldOBJ;
```

Add the custom fields to the issue query (and other main fields)

```
$issueQuery->customFieldValues = $customFields;
```

Create the issue ($token is your connection)

```
$issueCreated = $soapClient->createIssue($token, $demande);
```

Thats it! The $issueCreated will be the returned issue Key